# AllowInSecureProtocol All Modules

Tags: android, http, kotlin, gradle, proxy

There is a complex structure in my application. So it contains different modules. With Gradle 7.x, I need to make the necessary changes for the Insecure Protocol. But I have too many gradle files and too many maven { url 'http://' } available. Can I get all HTTP protocols accepted by editing from a specific location? Or should I make changes for each maven as follows. That means a lot of refactor :S
`

```
 {

         url 'http://'     
         allowInsecureProtocol = true

 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

sadly, this is not supported by Gradle. So you will have to continue opting in on each repository.
Read more here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18006